# How to add dictionary element stored in constant directly to dictionary literal in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm adding a specific dictionary element to multiple dictionaries, therefore I'd like to store this element in a constant so I can easily reuse it.

I like to do something like this:

```swift
let reusableElement: Dictionary<String, String>.Element = ("reusableKey", "reusableValue")

let dictUsingTheReusableElement: [String: Any] = ["name": "john",
                                                  "age": 15,
                                                  "legend": true,
                                                  reusableElement]
```

Which results the following error `Expected ':' in dictionary literal`.

Is there a way to directly insert the element in a dictionary literal? Or is it only possible to add this by doing something like this:

```swift
let dictUsingTheReusableElement: [String: Any] = ["name": "john",
                                                  "age": 15,
                                                  "legend": true,
                                                  reusableElement.0: reusableElement.1]
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson A dictionary `Element` is a tuple: `public typealias Element = (key: Key, value: Value)`. Changing it to what you have would result in a nested dictionary.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see the `.Element` part.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the difficult part with a dictionary literal is what it would do if the element's key was already in the literal.  You can see if you implement something like this:

```
let element: Dictionary<String, String>.Element = ("rK", "rV")

extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {
    func with(_ element: Element) -> Self {
        merging([element.0: element.1], uniquingKeysWith: { a, _ in a})
    }
}


let dictUsingTheReusableElement: [String: Any] = ["name": "john",
                                                  "age": 15,
                                                  "legend": true]
    .with(element)
```

You need to specify what to do with conflicts with that `uniquingKeys(with:`

And in fact if you do

```
let reusableElement: Dictionary<String, String>.Element = ("name", "foo")

let dictUsingTheReusableElement: [String: Any] = ["name": "john",
                                                  "age": 15,
                                                  "legend": true,
                                                  reusableElement.0: reusableElement.1]
```

You're going to have a runtime issue (*Swift/Dictionary.swift:826: Fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys*), so this is maybe why it's not a thing.